# Finding the 5 smallest numbers from a list in Python

Tags: python, sorting, max, minimum

I have a list of names,x, and a list of scores,y, that correspond to the names.

```
x = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k} 
y= {8,8,15,13,12,17,18,12,14,14}
```

So, a has score 8, b has scores 8, c has score 15, ..., k has score 14

I want to find the 5 smallest scores from the list,y, and get their name and have a print out similar to the following:

top5 lowest scores:

```
a : 8
b : 8 
e : 12
h : 12 
d : 13
```

Currently, I am creating a copy of the list and then using pop to keep reducing the list, but it is giving me incorrect names for the scores. However, when I create my list for the max5 values, everything comes out fine using the same method. I am unsure of a function that lets me do this in python. This is just a sample of my problem, my real problem involves store locations along with scores for those stores that I computed from a function, but I want to get the top 5 highest and 5 lowest scores. Does anyone have an efficient solution to this?

Comment: Your data structure is wrong. Use a dictionary.

Comment: `x = {1, 3, 4, 5}` is a set and its elements have random order, unlike a list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python has a data structure called `Dictionary` that you can use to store key/value pairs . In Python , dictionary is defined as -

```
dict = {'a':8 , 'b':8, 'c':15, 'd':13 ...}
```

Then you can iterate over the key value pairs in this dictionary to find the 5 smallest numbers.

You can convert the dict to a tuple and then sort the tuple based on the second item-

```
import operator
dict = {'a':8 , 'b':8, 'c':15, 'd':13 ...}
sorted_dict = sorted(dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Instead of using a dict, you can also use a `list of tuples`, and use the last line in above code to sort it based on the second element of each tuple.

The list of tuples would look like -

```
scores = [('a',8),('b',8),('c',15),('d',13)..]
```

Answer (score 2):

**First of all, organize your input collection**

Suppose you have input `x` and `y` where each of them is the collection of labels and score, respectively:

```
x = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'] 
y = [5,3,10,2,2,1,0]
```

To sort `x` by the corresponding score `y`, zip them together and sort by the score, take the first 5 and thats' it:

```
min_list = sorted(zip(x,y), key=lambda t: t[1])[5:]
```

> ***Quick explanation***
>
> It zips x and y together so you have a list of 
>        **zip(x,y)** = ('a',5), ('b',3), ...
>
> Then you sort that list by the second element of each tuple
>        **sorted( zip(x,y ))**
>        *where the key for sorting is the second element of tuple (t[1])*
>
> Lastly, take the first 5 elements of the sorted list
>        **[5:]**

Your resultant collection looks like this:

```
[('g', 0), ('f', 1), ('d', 2), ('e', 2), ('b', 3)]
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, then if say I wanted to print: 
'f': 1 how would I call the dictionary? print min_list[1][0], ':', 'min_list[1][1]?

Comment: and if I wanted to do the max I would just do min_list = sorted(zip(x,y), key=lambda t: t[1])[:5] instead of min_list = sorted(zip(x,y), key=lambda t: t[1])[5:]

Comment: Actually there are lots of built-in functions in Python which does your job. To find max in the list, you can do: `max(zip(x,y), key:lambda t: t[1])`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `{8,8,15...}` would create a `set`, not a `list`; as sets are not ordered, you cannot pair 2 sets together like this.

Thus you'd have

```
x = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k'] 
y = [8, 8, 15, 13, 12, 17, 18, 12, 14, 14]
```

Now, to make these into `letter, score` pairs, use the `zip` function.

```
pairs = zip(x, y)
```

And then you can find *n* smallest items with aptly named [`nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) function from the `heapq` module; you need to provide a custom `key` function that would provide the score for each item; we will use `operator.itemgetter(1)` for it (it would return the element `1` or the `score` for each `letter, score` pair:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from heapq import nsmallest

result = nsmallest(5, pairs, key=itemgetter(1))
print(result)
```

prints out

```
[('a', 8), ('b', 8), ('e', 12), ('h', 12), ('d', 13)]
```

To get the letters only, just add:

```
letters = [ i[0] for i in result ]
```